# VSTO, Outlook add-ins, and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, visual-studio-2015

Starting with Visual Studio RC, Visual Studio 2015 appears to no longer support the Office Add-In project types from Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO).   Lots of googlin' and questions to PMs in the MS blogs have revealed no useful information; but perhaps other in the community know more.  Opening a VSTO project yield "(incompatible)". so:

1. what is the status of VSTO and Visual Studio 2015
2. Is there a workaround to open the old project types in VS 2015

I don't have 2013 anymore because i wiped that machine...

Comment: I solved this.  It turns out it's only in enterprise VS not community edition.  Installed it; and it works fine.

Comment: Tried the link in Eguene Astafiev's answer, but got an error. This link should work, [https://www.visualstudio.com/features/office-tools-vs](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/office-tools-vs) Direct link to download here, [http://aka.ms/getlatestofficedevtools](http://aka.ms/getlatestofficedevtools)

Comment: I'm **wrong** it's not just in VS Enterprise.  Although it has the VSTO pieces.   Here is the answer I got from people at microsoft, in particular a pm who works in the area:  
  
    For the community edition, you can get the Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 through http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2015. Alternatively, you can always get the latest Office tooling through this page: https://vsstage.redmond.corp.microsoft.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.

Comment: vsstage.redmond.corp.microsoft.com/en-us/features/
Link above does not work

Comment: @toddwseattle I second Shailen Sukul comment: that link seems broken now

Answer (score 19):

Do you have the Community edition of VS installed?

Try to install https://aka.ms/getlatestofficedevtools .

Comment: Will this add it to community without going to enterprise?

Comment: Yes. It will. You need to use the installer in case of the Community edition.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Okay, so this worked great, but suddenly, for seemingly no reason at all, the error has returned. I was working in my new VSTO add-in just yesterday, publishing and re-publishing for various testing purposes, and now I go to open the project and I'm getting the "Install Missing Features . . . These Projects are not Supported" error.

Comment: Great, I installed the latest CTP version and now I can't even open 2013 add-ins. This is getting worse and worse.

Comment: @Lopsided -- This was working fine for me until I installed Windows 10 (was previously on 8.1). Now even with the latest Office Tools for VS 2015 installed I get this error when trying to open a VSTO project in VS 2015 Community. I guess I am back to using VS 2012 for VSTOs.

Comment: Once you've installed the tools for office development, what are the steps to follow with installing a vsto addin?

Comment: Thank you. But the link is valid.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like Microsoft is changing the link for getting the latest Office tools for VS.

Comment: This looked weird to me but worked well. thank you Eugene

Answer (score 4):

I am using VS 2015 Enterprise and I solved it with follow steps.

1. Edit office project 's .Csproj file with an XML editor
   find node: project\PropertyGroup, delete ProjectTypeGuids node;
2. close .sln.
3. reopen .sln.

My ProjectTypeGuids is `<ProjectTypeGuids>{BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`.

It seems VS can't recognize the typeGuids.

/**********Thanx Mogsdad for format my code**********/

When i try debug this project,i found it cant be debuged.Because it's projectType has losed.So i recover the .csproj file.

I notice another config node @`<Project><ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><FlavorProperties><ProjectProperties>`. This node has a attribute named `ApplicationType` and its value is 'XLS',i modified it to 'Excel',the project seems work fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from James Randal we found an answer. We created a brand new empty Sharepoint Add-in then compared a newly created .csproj XML with the OfficeDev PNP .csproj XML.

Deleting the GUID's above does not help as then Visual Studio does not recognize the project as a Sharepoint project.

Answer : Edit the .csproj XML to change <TargetOfficeVersion> 16.0 </TargetOfficeVersion>  to be **16.1** worked for me. You will still need to right-click on Sharepoint Project and install missing features but it finishes without the error message now.