# Migrate VS-2010 VSTO add-in to VS-2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, vsto

I tried migrating a solution from VS-2010 to VS-2015.
All projects succeed except my Word VSTO Add-In project.

It reported no errors during migration. It did report a warning though: `Visual Studio needs to make non-functional changes to this project in order to enable the project to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without impacting project behavior.`

But I think this is just a formality and doesn't indicate any actual problems.

The problems I experience is that VS-2015 doesn't seem to understand that this project is actually a VSTO project.
I Just can't figure out what the problem is.
None of the VSTO overrides or events are recognized.

I tried adding a new Word 2010 VSTO Add-In project, and the references and project properties seem to be exactly the same - only the new project works. The old does not.

Examples of errors I'm getting in the migrated VSTO project:

`Error BC30284` `function 'CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a function in a base class.`

Related code: `Protected Overrides Function CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject() As Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility`

-

`Error BC30590` `Event 'Startup' cannot be found.`

Related code: `Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup`

-

`Error BC30590` `Event 'Shutdown' cannot be found.`

Related code: `Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown`

-

Any tips on how to correct this is very welcome.
I have tried searching for similar problems here on StackOverflow and Google, but I've come up short of a useful answer.

Comment: Try this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570661/vsto-outlook-add-ins-and-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 0):

this is similar to this question posted on here, have a look :-

[VSTO, Outlook add-ins, and Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31570661/vsto-outlook-add-ins-and-visual-studio-2015)

thanks